# How to individually increase or decrease a value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to increase or decrease each products by clicking + or - button individually, but the issues is when I click any + button.. all products value is increased instead of one, same when i click - button. Kindly help me out how to do this

**jquery**

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
    $(".quantity-adder .add-action").click( function(){
        if( $(this).hasClass('add-up') ) {  
            $("[name=quantity]",'.quantity-adder').val( parseInt($("[name=quantity]",'.quantity-adder').val()) + 1 );
        }else {
            if( parseInt($("[name=quantity]",'.quantity-adder').val())  > 1 ) {
                $("input",'.quantity-adder').val( parseInt($("[name=quantity]",'.quantity-adder').val()) - 1 );
            }
        }
    } );

});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="product-extra">
    <p>Product 1</p>
                            <div class="quantity-adder pull-left">
                                <div class="quantity-number pull-left">
                                    <span>Qutantity</span>
                                    <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="quantity-wrapper pull-left">
                                    <span class="add-up add-action fa fa-plus"></span> 
                                    <span class="add-down add-action fa fa-minus"></span>
                                </div>                  
                                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="40" />   
                            </div>                                          

                    </div>
            <br /> 
                             <br /> 
                                   <br /> 

                       <div class="product-extra">
    <p>Product 2</p>
                            <div class="quantity-adder pull-left">
                                <div class="quantity-number pull-left">
                                    <span>Qutantity</span>
                                    <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="quantity-wrapper pull-left">
                                    <span class="add-up add-action fa fa-plus"></span> 
                                    <span class="add-down add-action fa fa-minus"></span>
                                </div>                  
                                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="44" />   
                            </div>                                          

                    </div>
                       <br /> 
                             <br /> 
                                   <br /> 
                                   <div class="product-extra">
    <p>Product 3</p>
                            <div class="quantity-adder pull-left">
                                <div class="quantity-number pull-left">
                                    <span>Qutantity</span>
                                    <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="quantity-wrapper pull-left">
                                    <span class="add-up add-action fa fa-plus"></span> 
                                    <span class="add-down add-action fa fa-minus"></span>
                                </div>                  
                                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="48" />   
                            </div>                                          

                    </div>
            <br /> 
                             <br /> 
                                   <br /> 

                       <div class="product-extra">
    <p>Product 4</p>
                            <div class="quantity-adder pull-left">
                                <div class="quantity-number pull-left">
                                    <span>Qutantity</span>
                                    <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="quantity-wrapper pull-left">
                                    <span class="add-up add-action fa fa-plus"></span> 
                                    <span class="add-down add-action fa fa-minus"></span>
                                </div>                  
                                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="55" />   
                            </div>                                          

                    </div>
                       <br /> 
                             <br /> 
                                   <br />
```

demo link
https://jsfiddle.net/sjyq64mj/

Comment: You need to target the *current item* rather than all items with a class

Comment: `<input type='number' />`

Comment: I would strongly recommend looking at something like knockout.js. It would make your life way easier and much more comfortable to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sjyq64mj/7/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".quantity-adder .add-action").click(function () {
         if ($(this).hasClass('add-up')) {
             var text = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("[name=quantity]", '.quantity-adder')


             text.val(parseInt(text.val()) + 1);
         } else {
             var text = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("[name=quantity]", '.quantity-adder')
             if (parseInt(text.val()) > 1) {


                text.val(parseInt(text.val()) - 1);
             }
         }
     });

 });
```

I added the `.parent()` so that then find the proper text to increase

Comment: @ShailendraSharma I was aiming for the div with the class `quantity-adder pull-left` just to be sure that it will be get the correct text to increase

Comment: have some issue with your Demo. Please check it again. Increase the quantity for 1st. Then go for second. It will fail. Please correct it

Comment: The Selector inside the .val() needs to be of the right quantity, too. Right now it takes the first value (cause jQuery returns an array)

Comment: @Pekka. I think you should use closest() to go to the correct parent directly (instead of parent().parent()...)

Comment: @Taleeb it was the first thing that came to my mind although closest can be used `.parent()` can also be used i merely giving option for the OP. I also believe that someone gave the answer using `.closest()` it would be an insult to the person if i copy his answer wouldn't it?

Comment: @Pekka, still there is problem with your fiddle.Why you are not updating your code present in `else` condition?`else {if (parseInt($("[name=quantity]", '.quantity-adder').val()`

Comment: Awesome....:) Thanks..! Just wanted to make sure other SO user will get correct code and will save their effort in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the correct control and increase/decrease the value. This can easily be done by using closest to go to the common parent div and then using find to select the correct control.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".quantity-adder .add-action").click(function () {
         var ctrl = $(this).closest('.quantity-adder').find("[name=quantity]", '.quantity-adder');
         if ($(this).hasClass('add-up')) {
             $(ctrl).val(parseInt($(ctrl).val()) + 1);
         } else {
             if (parseInt($(ctrl).val()) > 1) {
                 $(ctrl).val(parseInt($(ctrl).val()) - 1);
             }
         }
     });

 });
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/sjyq64mj/3/)

Alternatively you can use `<input type='number' min='1' value='1' />` for modern browsers (no need of any javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Working fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/sjyq64mj/5/

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
    $(".quantity-adder .add-action").click( function(){
        var qtyField = $(this).closest('.quantity-adder').find("[name=quantity]");

        if( $(this).hasClass('add-up') ) {  
            qtyField.val( parseInt(qtyField.val()) + 1 );
        }else {
            if( parseInt(qtyField.val())  > 1 ) {
                qtyField.val( parseInt(qtyField.val()) - 1 );
            }
        }
    } );

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `closest()`:

```js
//quantity text - box finder
var qty = function(el) {
  return $(el).closest('div.quantity-adder').find('input[type=text][name=quantity]').eq(0);
};

var plus = function(e) {
  var q = qty(this);
  q.val(1 + (+q.val() || 0));
};

var minus = function(e) {
  var q = qty(this);
  var v = (+q.val() || 0) - 1;
  if (1 > v)
    v = 1;
  q.val(v);
};

$(function() {
  $('span.fa-plus').on('click', plus);
  $('span.fa-minus').on('click', minus);
});
```

```css
.pull-left {
  float: left;
}
span.fa-plus:after {
  content: "+";
}
span.fa-minus:after {
  content: "-";
}
span.add-action {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-extra">
  <p>Product 1</p>
  <div class="quantity-adder pull-left">
    <div class="quantity-number pull-left">
      <span>Qutantity</span>
      <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="quantity-wrapper pull-left">
      <span class="add-up add-action fa fa-plus"></span> 
      <span class="add-down add-action fa fa-minus"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="40" />
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="product-extra">
  <p>Product 2</p>
  <div class="quantity-adder pull-left">
    <div class="quantity-number pull-left">
      <span>Qutantity</span>
      <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="quantity-wrapper pull-left">
      <span class="add-up add-action fa fa-plus"></span> 
      <span class="add-down add-action fa fa-minus"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="44" />
  </div>

</div>
<br />
<div class="product-extra">
  <p>Product 3</p>
  <div class="quantity-adder pull-left">
    <div class="quantity-number pull-left">
      <span>Qutantity</span>
      <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="quantity-wrapper pull-left">
      <span class="add-up add-action fa fa-plus"></span> 
      <span class="add-down add-action fa fa-minus"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="48" />
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="product-extra">
  <p>Product 4</p>
  <div class="quantity-adder pull-left">
    <div class="quantity-number pull-left">
      <span>Qutantity</span>
      <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="quantity-wrapper pull-left">
      <span class="add-up add-action fa fa-plus"></span> 
      <span class="add-down add-action fa fa-minus"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="55" />
  </div>
</div>
```