# combine jquery and kendo example

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui

I found a [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861835/how-to-individually-increase-or-decrease-a-value-using-jquery/32861962) and reduce the working example to an input field where a number is displayed and two buttons where you can in- and decrease the value of integer by click as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pw1L6nx0/1/).

```html
...
 <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
...
<div class="quantity-wrapper pull-left">
   <span class="add-up add-action fa fa-plus"></span>
   <span class="add-down add-action fa fa-minus"></span>
 </div>
...
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $(".quantity-adder .add-action").click(function () {
         if ($(this).hasClass('add-up')) {
             var text = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("[name=quantity]", '.quantity-adder')
             text.val(parseInt(text.val()) + 1);
         } else {
             var text = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("[name=quantity]", '.quantity-adder')
             if (parseInt(text.val()) > 1) {
                 
             
                text.val(parseInt(text.val()) - 1);
             }
         }
     });

 });
```

I want to add a kendo dropdownlist as I tried in [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/9uv17br4/11). But the +/- buttons are missing. Can someone pls tell me how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this. Try this in the Telerik DOJO. I'll leave the CSS stuff to you. If you are going to reuse this functionality then I'd suggest creating this into a custom Widget. See Kendo documentation for extending the `Widget` class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="dropdownlist" />
  <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
  
  <div class="quantity-wrapper">
    <button class="up">+</button>
    <button class="down">-</button>
 </div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $quantity = $("[name=quantity]");
    $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
      dataSource: {
        data: ["Banana", "Lemon"]
      }
    });

    $(".quantity-wrapper").on("click", "button", function () {
      var quantity = parseInt($quantity.val());
      
      if ($(this).hasClass("up")) {
        $quantity.val(quantity + 1);
      } else {
        if (quantity > 1) {
          $quantity.val(quantity - 1);
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<style>
  .quantity-wrapper {
    display: inline-grid;
  }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add buttons instead of span

```
<div class="quantity-wrapper pull-left">
            <button class="add-up add-action fa fa-plus">+</button>
            <button class="add-down add-action fa fa-minus">-</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Did u tried it before? I c/p it to the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/2urcdm6s/) with no effect.